# Folder is not being deleted from docker container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to delete php.ini folder from php container via Dockerfile.
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitnami/php-fpm:latest 
RUN rm -rf /opt/bitnami/php/lib/php.ini
RUN ls /opt/bitnami/php/lib
```

Then I run `sudo docker build --no-cache --progress=plain .` and see no `php.ini` folder in it's output. Moreover, I don't see it even without this `rm -rf` step. It seems like it's no such folder in that image at all.

But when I run `sudo docker compose up --build -d` and then `sudo docker exec php-fpm ls /opt/bitnami/php/lib`, I see that folder there.

Php service in docker-compose.yml:

```
  php:
    build: .
    container_name: php-fpm
    hostname: php-fpm
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - "ENV_SUBSTITUTION_ENABLE=true"
      - "PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=512M"
      - "PHP_FPM_LISTEN=9000"
      - "PHP_SESSION_GC_MAXLIFETIME=7200"
    volumes:
      - ./projmain:/var/www/proj:rw
```

Full docker-compose.yml: https://pastebin.com/Z7ZuhVs4

Comment: My first question would be: Why are you trying to delete the php.ini file? Are you sure the path to the file is correct? When I did a Google search, I found "/opt/bitnami/php/etc/conf.d/" as the directory where you can place your custom ini files.

Comment: Please [edit] the file to include the Compose file (or a minimal excerpt) directly in the question.  I can imagine things like an `image:` declaration or a `volumes:` mount causing the trouble, but it's hard to tell given only an external URL.

Comment: @GlennM It seems like it's not even a file, but an empty folder. I am trying to delete it because I wanted to mount a default php.ini file at such path (a single file, not a folder), but got an error, presumably, because I was trying to mount file on a folder. Path is correct, I could check it with "ls" and copy it's contents from docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze Maze What is wrong with external link? Wouldn't it look ugly if I paste whole file's contents in a question? What if my file would contain more than 1000 strings?

Comment: @Roman2903 You should be able to mound files as well as folders in the "volumes" section. But of course left and right side of the : should be of the same type (mount a folder to a Docker folder, or a file to a file in Docker)